# How to decrease brackets size?

Tags: brackets, size

As stated in the subject, I know that `$\left[x\right]$` can be used to increase the size of the brackets to adjust for a large argument, but what about if instead I would like to  decrease the brackets size in order to enclose it without leaving unnecessary vertical space below and above it?

Comment: dont use `\left\right`  just choose a suitable size such as `\bigl(...\bigr)`

Comment: What I would need is more something like `\smalll(...\smalll)`

Comment: `\scriptstyle(a+b)` but as you have provided no example it is hard to answer with specific code